# getting and passing around id of DOM element in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to get the id of an element from the DOM inside a controller and depending on the id the corresponding form will form will show.

I could easily make two separate views for each id but that's just the dirty way.

```
<a id="transcript" href="#/pdfView" ng-click="showId($event)" data="transcript">--><img src="assets/images/graduation22.png" id="view-transcript"></a>
```

I have tried using the `$scope` to get and return the elements id inside the controller using the ng-click directive.

```
$scope.ShowId = function(event)
{
    if(event.target.id == 'transcript'){
        $scope.url = 'assets/documents/binder1.pdf';
    }
    else{
        $scope.url = 'assets/documents/KeilCarpenterCV.pdf';
    }
};
```

Then send the value of 'url' to ng-src attr on the directive template:

```
<pdfviewer ng-src="{{url}}" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer"></pdfviewer>
```

but this does nothing.

As i mentioned above, I could just have two separate views one for each document but that just sounds rediculas.

So what is the best way to get and pass around id's in angular?

Comment: Your scope function is `ShowId` (capital "S") but your `ng-click` directive is attempting to execute `showId` (lowercase "s").

Comment: also, you can try doing a $scope.$apply() at the end of the function

Comment: I would also recommend simply passing the arguments to `ShowId` directly. For example, `ng-click="ShowId(true)"` and use `$scope.ShowId = function(isTranscript) { $scope.url = isTranscript ? '...binder1.pdf' : '...KeilCarpenterCV.pdf'; }`

Comment: @jhonquintero no, that will throw a "digest already in progress" error

Comment: Did you try troubleshooting with console.log for $scope.url and event.target.id? Does the right values get passed? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: by doing a log on $scope.url inside the function nothing is passed so somithing must be missing elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - Its was because the function was in the wrong controller